# How to group by a specific cell and then send email to respective IDs in google sheets?

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's a sample dataset I have

[image]

In apps script I want this data to be divided by sender like for example for hub1 would be

[image]

and then in another sheet I have the following data

[image]

and then send that specific hub's table to that specific hub's email address.

I've already made the code to send the emails to all the hubs which are entered, but how to slice the data per hub for each hub and send that data only I am not able to do.
Kindly help!

Comment: About `I've already made the code to send the emails to all the hubs which are entered, but how to slice the data per hub for each hub and send that data only I am not able to do.`, can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently. Cannot find a helper at that time so I make personal lib. See the file to copy in a new .gs file at the link : https://github.com/SolannP/UtilsAppSsript/blob/main/UtilsGSheetTableHelper.gs

You can use the code bellow to adapt to feet your needs :

```js
// get range of all cell near A1 with value, in your case something like A1:B5 (email and HubName)
var contactData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_WITH_YOUR_EMAIL_DATA").getRange("A1").getDataRegion();
// get range of all cell near A1 with value, in your case A1:C7
var tableData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_WITH_YOUR_DATA_SET").getRange("A1").getDataRegion();
// create special table of contact
var specialTableContact = new TableWithHeaderHelper(contactData);
// create special table of data set 
var specialTableData = new TableWithHeaderHelper(tableData);

// for each row in the table of contact
for(var i=0 ; i < specialTableContact.length() ; i++){
  var email = specialTableContact.getWithinColumn("EmailID").cellAtRow(i);
  var hubName = specialTableContact.getWithinColumn("HubName").cellAtRow(i);

  //create a sub table for matching hubName
  var filterDataOnHubName = specialTableData.getTableWhereColumn("Sender").matchValue(hubName)
  // Some data for later use
  var summaryDataForEmail = "";
  var cost="";
  var idProduct="";
  // for each row in the table product matching current HubName
  for(var j=0; j < filterDataOnHubName.length() ; j++){
    cost = filterDataOnHubName.getWithinColumn("Cost").cellAtRow(j).getValue();
    idProduct = filterDataOnHubName.getWithinColumn("ProductID").cellAtRow(j).getValue();
    summaryDataForEmail = summaryDataForEmail+ `${idProduct} at ${cost}.`

  }
  // ... do watever you want 
  // something like 
  // MailApp.sendEmail({
  //  to:email ,
  //  subject: "some subject",
  //  cc:"anyone in copy",
  //  htmlBody:summaryDataForEmail,
  // });
}
```

Speed is not optimized but at least it's not so hard to grasp what the code is doing in 30~40 lines of code.